# How to specify / set priority for the route to the internet?

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, network-interface

I have a subnet with access to the internet and one without. When using commands such as: `sudo apt-get update` the console hangs for a couple of seconds, before finding the correct route I assume. I am setting manual ip addresses in the /network/interfaces file.

To clarify: I have several static addresses set inside the interfaces file but would like to be able to specify the address and default gateway to use when trying to access the internet vs. communicating on subnets

If anyone could point me into the right direction I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Please add either `netstat -rn` or `ip route` to your question

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with DNS than routes, at least to me. XY problem?